# Fast algorithm for finding fewest k-mers that cover regions of string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, combinatorics, bloom-filter

I have a string representing the human genome, which is a quaternary code (`alphabet = {A, C, T, G}`):

```
str = 'ACTGGTGCGAGACTGCGGGAACACTGAGCGGGCGAGACT'
```

The problem is, by dividing the string into substring of size `bin_size`, I wish to find the ***fewest unique, non-overlapping k-mers*** that span some threshold `T` length for each substring.

For instance, for `k=3`, `bin_size = 10`, and `T = 0.6`, it takes only **2 unique, non-overlapping 3-mers** `ACT` & `GCG` to span 6 characters of each substring of length 10:

```
ACTGGTGCGA GACTGCGGGA ACACTGAGCG GGCGAGACT
```

One approach I have in mind is to count the k-mers with a Bloom filter first, and check each substring for the most popular k-mers. But the non-overlapping criteria, and that I want to find the fewest unique k-mers, suggest this could be written as an optimization problem (somehow). Is there already an existing algorithm that solves something like this?

** EDIT: **
Practically speaking, `k=16`, `bin_size = 1 000 000`, and total length of string `len(str) = 3 000 000 000`.

The k-mers should, in practice, not overlap more than some overlap ie. `overlap = 3 letters`.

Comment: Is there a space missing between the middle 'AA' in your example? And am I understanding correctly that `bin_size * T` would always be some non-zero integer multiple of `k`, given that the k-mers have to be non-overlapping and would together have to cover `T/1` of each bin? Or could `T` be smaller and one or two of the k-mers would sit partially outside the bin?

Comment: Hi @Grismar, which AA are you referring to? The string `str = ...` should be equivalent to the bottom, bolded string.

Comment: I made an edit - it was a font thing, the space was there, but didn't render as clearly visible due to the font. Hope this is clearer to all. How about the second question?

Comment: The second question is an important one, `bin_size * T` need not be an integer multiple of `k`, but for simplicity I can make it so! `T` cannot be smaller s.t. one of the 2 k-mers sit outside the bin.

Comment: As I have recently learned, this might be related to **universal hitting sets**, which appears to be an NP-complete problem...

Comment: Do you require the k-mers themselves to be non-overlapping, or only their appearances in each string?

Comment: Let n be the number of bins and m = T\*bin_size/k be the number of k-mers needed per bin. Sum the k-mer frequencies in decreasing order until you reach nm -- the number of terms in the sum is a lower bound on the number of k-mers you need. This will be very loose, but: This procedure continues to give a valid bound if you delete a k-mer and all bins it is present in (thus reducing n). If you delete, say, the most-frequent 90% of k-mers and the bins in which they appear, I think you'll find that many bins remain (these contain just infrequent k-mers) and the lower bound produced will be high.

Comment: @גלעדברקן In practice, k is ~ 16, although 32 would be ideal (and computationally expensive). bin_size = 1 000 000, and string length is 3 000 000 000.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the k-mers themselves need to be non-overlapping! Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: In that case there are problem instances with no solution, e.g.: bins = ["AC", "CT"], k = 2.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I see your point. I have updated my problem

Comment: @גלעדברקן there's actually 3000 bins, the genome is 3 billion letters long, each bin is 1 million letters long

Comment: Yes, there's a reduction from hitting set, so you shouldn't hope for a polynomial time algorithm. A mixed integer program solver will likely work well though, especially if you settle for a possibly suboptimal solution by discarding less frequent k-mers at the outset.

Comment: I'd start by transforming the input string into a table of k-mers, with a list of indexes for each k-mer. [The sample string in the question transforms to this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G84gk.png) The table contains frequency information, as well as positional information for every possible k-mer. It allows you to quickly determine the overlaps between common k-mers. For example, notice that `GAG` and `GCG` overlap by 1 character at three different positions. The only instance of `GCG` that doesn't overlap `GAG` is at index 14 in the string.

Comment: For k=16, there are M=4294967296 possible k-mers. Given a string length of N=3000000000, it would require 44GB of memory to create the table of indexes. It would take two O(N) passes of the string, and one O(M) pass of the table to complete the table. So definitely doable on a machine with 64GB of memory, and not too time consuming in relation to the size of the input.